# ExtJs 6 Htmleditor in propertygrid

Tags: javascript, html-editor, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I want to use **HtmlEditor** in **PropertyGrid** and my framework version is **ExtJS 
6.0.0.640** . But, I have a problem with this...

When I use **Htmleditor** to **propertygrid** a conflict to display. Yet, I change framework version to 4 not problem.

For example, The following link and change framework version to 6.0.1.250. You'll see not a problem the first time.

But, You do on a column sorting you will see that a problem to display.

[Htmleditor to propertygrid](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2dj)

My code :

```
Ext.define('Draw.view.mainmap.MainMap',{
   extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
   xtype: 'myGrid',
   layout: 'fit',
   width: 400,
   items: [{
      title: 'property grid',
      xtype: 'propertygrid',
      source: {
         "(name)": "My Object",
         "Available" : false,
         "Version" : 0.01,
         "Description" : "A test Object"
      },
      customEditors: {
         Description: {
            xtype: 'htmleditor',   
         }
      }
   }]
});
```

Comment: so what is your question?